# Can not make nginx reverse proxy work with Keystone

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, keystonejs

I'm learning Keystone, trying to deploy onto Digital Ocean. I can clone and make Keystone runs like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
Example Site is ready on port 3000
------------------------------------------------
```

I followed the book, setup nginx like this

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name examplesite.com;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

The domain's DNS is pointed to Digital Ocean, and it worked fine with my old WordPress version. I've just destroyed the droplet, and reinstalled everything, so this is not domain's problem.

Despite I did anything, I still can not reach the Keystone:

```
This site can’t be reached
examplesite.com took too long to respond.
```

Some information:
Node: v4.5.0
npm: v3.10.6
Ubuntu: 16.04

Please help.

Comment: first double check, locally running curl command

Comment: curl http://localhost.3000

Comment: @enRaiser : When I curl, it returned the rendered html code. That's mean the node app is running ok, right?

I ping my domain and it returns server's IP. So what is the problem here, I don't know.

Btw, I set up the same on Google Compute Engine, and it works.

Comment: yes that means node is runnig fine. now you need to focus on nignx

Comment: give me ur email ID , I will send my nginx.conf may be  it can help you. I am also runnig on digital ocian

Comment: Thank you, sangdth@gmail.com